# Powershell : Send Pipe as argument to the command

Tags: powershell, foreach, escaping, pipe, command-line-arguments

I'm working on command which looks something like below -

```
$command="Path to Command / Bat file"  
$delim = [RegEx]::Escape("|")

(Get-ChildItem -Path .\ -Force).Name | % { &"$command"
".\$_" "$delim" "..\<SomePath>\$_.html"}
```

Issue am facing is with Passing the delim value which is Pipe in this case. Delim is the second argument to my command.

What's happening is the "..\\$_.html" is getting executed as an executable but it must be passed as third argument.

Answer (score 1):

Simply *quote* the `|` character to pass it to an external program. The quoting is needed to tell *PowerShell* that `|` is to be interpreted *literally* rather than as the pipeline operator.

```sh
PS> 'a|b' | & findstr /L '|'  # findstr.exe sees a literal | char.; & is optional here
a|b  # Literal '|' was found in input string 'a|b'
```

The only time additional work is needed is if the target program *itself* treats *unquoted* `|`<sup>[1]</sup> as having special meaning, notably when invoking `cmd.exe` or a batch file.

The most robust solution is to pass a whole command line *as a single string* to `cmd.exe`:

```sh
PS> cmd /c 'echo "|"'
"|"
```

(It is a quirk of `cmd.exe`'s internal `echo` command that the double quotes are *retained* in this case.)

Even *batch files* can be called this way, which additionally also enables working around a problem with unreliably reported exit codes - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66250528/45375).

```sh
cmd /c 'someFile.cmd "|" & exit'
```

---

<sup>[1] Even though `'|'` is quoted in the *PowerShell* command line above, behind the scenes PowerShell passes it *unquoted*, which it does whenever an argument has no embedded *spaces*.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer to my problem. We need to use it in the following way instead regular expression. This is because the 'c' engine does not support regex separators.

```
$command="Path to Command / Bat file"  

(Get-ChildItem -Path .\ -Force).Name | % { &"$command"
".\$_" `"`|`" "..\<SomePath>\$_.html"}
```